# Temperature numbers in map marker in Folium

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I would like to add temperatures for a set of specific latitudes and longitudes in a map using folium, in folium we have markers and popups is there a way to add numbers like the one attached?

[image]

i have a simple code for markers and popups

```
import os
import folium
m = folium.Map(
    location=[27.6648, -81.5158],
    zoom_start=12,
    #tiles='Mapbox Bright'
)

folium.Marker([27.6648, -81.5158], popup='<i>test mountain</i>').add_to(m)
folium.Marker([27.2648, -81.4158], popup='<b>mountain2 Lodge</b>',icon=folium.Icon(color='red')).add_to(m)
m.save(os.path.join('simple_popups.html'))
```

i am getting markers and popups like this

[image]

Can we achieve this using folium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [DivIcon](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.features.DivIcon) for this:

```
icon = folium.DivIcon(html="your temperature here")
folium.Marker([27.2648, -81.4158], icon=icon).add_to(m)
```